# How do I implement a search form in lift that displays the results on the same page, and remembers the input?

Tags: scala, lift

In Lift, I am trying to make a feature where the user can input an order number and get back the results on the same page as the form, and have the form remember the input. Here is the HTML:

```
<form data-lift="ordersearchform?form=post">
    Order Number: <input name="ordernumber"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th id="tableheaderentries"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr><td id="myrowsoftabledata"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<div class="lift:Msgs?showAll=true"></div>
```

Here is my attempt at the scala code:

```
import scala.xml.{ NodeSeq, Text }
import net.liftweb.util._
import net.liftweb.common._
import java.util.Date
import code.lib._
import Helpers._
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers._
import net.liftweb.http.S
import net.liftweb.http.SHtml
import net.liftweb.http.StatefulSnippet

import _root_.net.liftweb.mapper._
import code.model._

class ordersearchform extends StatefulSnippet {

  private var ordernumber: String = ""
  private val whence = S.referer openOr "/"

  def dispatch: DispatchIt = { case "render" => render _ }

  def render(xhtml : NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = {

    "@ordernumber" #> SHtml.text(ordernumber, ordernumber = _) &
    "type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(process)

  }

  def process() {
      val fieldNames: List[String] = List("Order Number", "Buyer", "Supplier")
      val fieldValues = Order.findAll(Like(Order.ordernumber, s"%$ordernumber%"))

      println(fieldNames)
      "#tableheaderentries *" #> fieldNames
      "#myrowsoftabledata *" #> fieldValues.map(values => "td *" #> values) 

    // }
  }

}
```

I came with this based on:

[The StatefulSnippet API](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/net/liftweb/http/StatefulSnippet.html), from which I gather that render must be function that transforms NodeSeq to NodeSeq;
[Lift in Action source code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/2011658/), which in retrospect I find might not be applicable;
[Exploring Lift sample code](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.3.html), which is the basis for my submit form above, but does not do any CSS selector transformations (which is what I need to do);
[More Exploring Lift sample code](http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-5.html), which also shows that maybe I should try making the render function transform NodeSeq to Nodeq, but I can't figure out how to solve this particular issue using this approach. I am also drawing on a recipe from [Simply Lift, chapter 14](http://simply.liftweb.net/index-Chapter-14.html#toc-Chapter-14). I was hoping that [this SO Question would help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003362/scala-lift-css-selector-transforms-and-dispatchsnippet), because it is directly relevant, but the accepted answer (posted by the author) didn't help since it didn't contain the snippet code.

The above scala code will not compile; I get the following error:

```
[error]  found   : net.liftweb.util.CssSel
[error]  required: scala.xml.NodeSeq
[error]     "@ordernumber" #> SHtml.text(ordernumber, ordernumber = _) &
[error]                                                       ^
[error] one error found
```

Do I need to use the bind function and a template? Should I not do NodeSeq to NodeSeq? I want to extend StatefulSnippet and process the form, but I can't figure out how to do a CSS Selector Transform to present the data if I take this approach.

There was a question on the lift google group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/1nP1B9QAU34), but the question wasn't solved. Can anyone please advise?

UPDATE 9/27/2014: I am trying the advice that @jcern gave in a comment to this post. When I change `def render(xhtml : NodeSeq)` to `def render:NodeSeq=>NodeSeq = {`

I get the following error:

```
[error]  found   : () => scala.xml.NodeSeq => scala.xml.NodeSeq
[error]  required: scala.xml.NodeSeq => scala.xml.NodeSeq
[error]   def dispatch: DispatchIt = { case "render" => render _ }
[error]                                                 ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

When I remove the type signature completely (i.e. change to `def render = {`), I get the following error when trying to compile:

```
[error]  found   : () => net.liftweb.util.CssSel
[error]  required: scala.xml.NodeSeq => scala.xml.NodeSeq
[error]   def dispatch: DispatchIt = { case "render" => render _ }
[error]                                                 ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

I think that using `Memoize` is the way to solve this issue. Just wondering whether I can solve it using a post and reload...

Comment: Looks like your return type is incorrect. Can you try making the signature either: `def render: CssSel` or `def render:NodeSeq=>NodeSeq` or just remove the type signature completely?

Comment: @jcern: Thanks for commenting. I tried your advice but I still get compile errors. I have updated the question to show the output from using your suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, I missed how you were invoking the snippet. It looks like you are using a method from `DispatchSnippet` without mixing in the trait though (not sure if that happens elsewhere in your code). Since you only have one method, I would probably remove the `dispatch...` line entirely and just have the render method with one of the signatures I suggested. If you want to keep it though, one last thing to try is calling `apply` with the `NodeSeq` on the result of the render method like this: `def render(xhtml : NodeSeq) : NodeSeq = { ... your code... }.apply(xhtml)`

Comment: @jcern: Thanks - with your suggested changes, the code now compiles error-free. The `process()` function, however, does not change the page at all (it does get executed, but it doesn't change the page output). Can you suggest changes to the `process()` method to get it to change insert the `tableheaderentries`, etc.?

Comment: If you want the page to update dynamically, you'd need to use AJAX for handling the events. It's a pretty simple switch, you'd just replace `onSubmitUnit` with `ajaxSubmit` and then make your `process()` method return a `JsCmd` which handles the page update, probably something like: `JsCmds.SetHtml("#tableheaderentries", fieldNames)`. Or, if you have a complex structure, you could memoize it when it is rendered the first time and then on submit, you'd just return `memo.setHtml()` in your submit action.

Comment: @jcern: Later I'll try to get the `JsCmds` approach working and then post the solution here, but I think `memoize` is the way to go. Thanks for your help.